# Ember importing value and compute function

Tags: function, ember.js, components

I have range with currentValue displayed in span. I'm trying to import this value to compute function, make a calculation and return back.
I stacked in compute.

range.hbs

```
<input
type="range"
onchange={{action 'valueChanged' value='target.value'}}
class="form-control"
value="{{currentValue}}" <!-- this value i get from outside, it's 50 and range shows 50 too -->
min="1"
max="99"
id="rangeValue"

/>

<span class="tag tag-pill tag-info">
   {{currentValue}}% - {{deltaValue}}%
</span>
```

range.js

```
export default FormComponent.extend({
didInsertElement(){
    // show initial value:
    var rangeValue = $('#rangeValue').val();
    console.log(rangeValue);
    // output of console: 50 
}

deltaValue: computed('currentValue', function() {
    var newValue = 100 - this.get('currentValue');  
    console.log(newValue)
    // output in console: 100
  })
});
```

from deltaValue I need to get 50 instead of 100

Comment: Have you checked if your computed function is called after you change the currentValue? For example with a `console.log` in your function

Comment: yes, in my console computed function is working. It's changing values.
But it doesnt display the initial value (which is 50). As soon as I run the code in the console I get null, after when i change the range computed function is working. But my goal is that, computed function takes currentValue (50) make a newValue (100 - 50) and return 50

Comment: Where have you defined the initial value? Will the component receive it from the outside world? Or do you use a hook for this? Can you please edit your code to show me?

Comment: Hey Shimu,
I added some comments and edited code. The currentValue in input I get from outside. Just I dont have ni cluehow i can import this value into computed function

Comment: Do you also hava an element with the id rangeValue or do you mean the input element? Also, as a start value you want the currenValue, right?

Comment: the id was just to pass value to js to check in the console the currentValue.  yes yes, currentValue is a start value

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible solutions:

a.) You pass an initial value to the function

```
{{input-range-component
  currentValue=50
}}
```

b.) You set an initial Value in a hook

```
export default FormComponent.extend({
  didReceiveAttrs(){
    this.set('currentValue', 50);
  }

  deltaValue: computed('currentValue', function() {
    var newValue = 100 - this.get('currentValue');  
    console.log(newValue)
    // output in console: 100
  })
});
```

This hook has the advantage that it always will be called and the initial value will be set what you want.

Make sure that you really set the property `currentValue` of your component